# CUDA 9.1 install on Ubuntu 18.04 on an online Google VM

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, kernel, cuda

When I try to install the NVIDIA driver, I run this command:

```
 sudo bash cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux --verbose --override --kernel- 
 source-path=/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0
```

...and it tells me that it is unable to locate kernel source and headers

Note: I have already installed the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit before the driver and I am not using an X environment`

On further inspection, it also shows this:

```
ERROR: Neither the '/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0/include/linux/version.h' nor the
   '/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
   ' kernel header file exists. The most likely reason for this is
   that the kernel source files in '/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0'  
   have not been configured.
```

I have managed to get further by copying version.h from the `/usr/include/linux` directory, but it now complains:

```
Error 1
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
././include/linux/kconfig.h:5:10: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h:   
No such file or directory  
#include <generated/autoconf.h>
```

How do I get the generated folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the NVIDIA NGC instance fixed it
I just had to go to this link:
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/nvidia-ngc-public/nvidia_gpu_cloud_image

And use some of my £300 credit that comes free for 365 days on google cloud platform

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit  your question  to expand it with specific details about what you do.

Answer (score 0):

The installer is looking for a file at `${source-path}/include/linux/version.h`

If I do a search for version.h at /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0, this is what I get:

```
$ find /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0/ -name 'version.h'
./linux-source-4.15.0/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/include/VBox/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/arch/x86/math-emu/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/drivers/net/ethernet/chelsio/cxgb3/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/drivers/staging/media/atomisp/pci/atomisp2/css2400/css_2401_system/hrt/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/drivers/staging/media/atomisp/pci/atomisp2/css2400/css_2400_system/hrt/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/drivers/staging/media/atomisp/pci/atomisp2/css2400/css_2401_csi2p_system/hrt/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
./linux-source-4.15.0/include/xen/interface/version.h
```

So it's not there. :-(

According to the [Ubuntu packages directory](http://packages.ubuntu.com), the file [does exist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=include%2Flinux%2Fversion.h&mode=&suite=bionic&arch=any) with that partial path in the `linux-libc-dev` package.

Try installing that and then specifying the source-path as `/usr`.

Comment: I just tried that and it hasn't made a difference

Comment: Updated my answer.  Try it with the directory below since they seem to have included it in a directory with the version name in the tar archive.

Comment: I tried that as well and the output hasn't changed, it still says that it can't find the version.h file in that location

Comment: thinking about it, it may be that cuda 9.1 doesn't support that kernel version, I am only using it because torch is not compatible cuda 10. It doesn't say in the documentation anything about 18.04

Comment: I've done that but it says the paths is invalid, as it is probably looking for specific files in there

Comment: Can you update your question, please?  It probably needs headers and source specified separately.